# ¿porqué estos input no se suman?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hay una suma que no se completa y no sé porqué. Vean el fragmento de mi código:

```html
<table align="left" width="45%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
     <tr>
         <td colspan="12"><h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;I. Conteo de Efectivo</h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr bordercolor="#000000">
        <td>Monedas de ¢5</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cinco" id="a" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Monedas de ¢5" onchange="multiplicara(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Monedas de ¢10</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="diez" id="b" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Monedas de ¢10" onchange="multiplicarb(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Monedas de ¢25</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="veinticinco" id="c" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Monedas de ¢25" onchange="multiplicarc(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Monedas de ¢50</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cincuenta" id="d" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Monedas de ¢50" onchange="multiplicard(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Monedas de ¢100</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cien" id="e" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Monedas de ¢100" onchange="multiplicare(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Monedas de ¢500</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quinientos" id="f" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Monedas de ¢500" onchange="multiplicarf(); suma();" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot5" id="aA" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢5" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot10" id="bB" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢10" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot25" id="cC" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢25" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot50" id="dD" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢50" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot100" id="eE" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢100" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot500" id="fF" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢500" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr bordercolor="#000000">
        <td>Billetes ¢1,000</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mil" id="A" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Billetes de ¢1,000" onchange="multiplicarA(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Billetes ¢2,000</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="2mil" id="B" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Billetes de ¢2,000" onchange="multiplicarB(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Billetes ¢5,000</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="5mil" id="C" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Billetes de ¢5,000" onchange="multiplicarC(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Billetes ¢10,000</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="10mil" id="D" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Billetes de ¢10,000" onchange="multiplicarD(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Billetes ¢20,000</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="20mil" id="E" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Billetes de ¢20,000" onchange="multiplicarE(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Billetes ¢50,000</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="50mil" id="F" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Billetes de ¢50,000" onchange="multiplicarF(); suma();" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot1" id="AA" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢1,000" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot2" id="BB" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢2,000" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot5" id="CC" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢5,000" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot10" id="DD" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢10,000" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot20" id="EE" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢20,000" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot50" id="FF" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢50,000" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
        <td colspan="12">Total Efectivo:&nbsp;<b style="font-size:200%;">¢</b><input type="text" name="totEfectivo" id="totEfectivo" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93; font-size:200%;" size="5" onchange="sumados();" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

En donde el input 'resultante' es este:

```
<td colspan="12">Total Efectivo:&nbsp;<b style="font-size:200%;">¢</b><input type="text" name="totEfectivo" id="totEfectivo" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93; font-size:200%;" size="5" onchange="sumados();" /></td>
```

Luego, el siguiente bloque, donde deseo sumar el input 'resultante' con el anterior es este:

```html
<table align="right" width="45%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
     <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><h1>&nbsp;II. Conteo de Datafóno</h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Terminal ID:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="terminal" id="terminal" readonly="readonly" value="00121509" title="ID del terminal, Banco Nacional" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Lote #:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lote" id="lote" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" placeholder="Número de Lote (cierre)" title="Número de Lote (cierre)" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Número de Ventas:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="ventanum" id="ventanum" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" maxlength="2" placeholder="Número de Ventas" title="Número de Ventas" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Monto Ventas ¢:</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="quitar" name="montovta" id="montovta" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" maxlength="10" placeholder="Total de Ventas" title="Total de Ventas" value="0" onchange="resta();" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Número de Devoluciones:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="devonum" id="devonum" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" maxlength="2" placeholder="Número de Devoluciones" title="Número de Devoluciones" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Monto Devoluciones ¢:</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="quitar" name="montodevo" id="montodevo" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" maxlength="10" placeholder="Total de Devoluciones" title="Total de Devoluciones" value="0" onchange="resta();" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Fecha de Transacción:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="fecha" id="fecha" title="Fecha de Transacción" readonly="readonly" value="<?php $fecha = date("d/m/Y"); echo $fecha; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
        <td colspan="2">Total Venta Tarjetas&nbsp;<b style="font-size:200%;">¢</b><input type="text" name="totaltdc" id="totaltdc" title="Total Ventas Tarjeta" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93; font-size:200%;" size="5" onchange="sumados();" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

En donde el input 'resultante' de este bloque es este:

```
<td colspan="2">Total Venta Tarjetas&nbsp;<b style="font-size:200%;">¢</b><input type="text" name="totaltdc" id="totaltdc" title="Total Ventas Tarjeta" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93; font-size:200%;" size="5" onchange="sumados();" /></td>
```

Ahora, al sumar estos dos input, el resultado deseo que lo reciba en este bloque:

```html
<table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="45%">
     <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><h1>&nbsp;III. Datos del turno</h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Turno en el que reporta el Cierre:</td>
        <td><select name="turno" title="Seleccione el Turno"><option value="">Seleccione...</option><option value="AM">AM</option><option value="PM">PM</option></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Hora:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="hora" title="Hora Actual" value="<?php date_default_timezone_set('America/Costa_Rica'); $now = date("H:i:s"); echo $now; ?>" readonly="readonly" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Inicio de Caja ¢:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="iniciar" id="iniciar" title="Monto al iniciar jornada" value="25000" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" maxlength="6" onchange="operacion();" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Ventas Facturadas en Mónica ¢:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="vtas" id="vtas" value="0" title="Monto vendido en Mónica" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" maxlength="6" onchange="operacion();" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Conteo total Fin de Turno ¢:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="finturno" id="finturno" value="0" title="Conteo total Fin de Turno" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93;" onchange="operacion();" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Diferencia ¢:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="diferencia" id="diferencia" value="0" title="Sobrante o Faltante" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93;" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

En concreto, deseo que el valor lo reciba este input:

```
<td><input type="text" name="diferencia" id="diferencia" value="0" title="Sobrante o Faltante" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93;" /></td>
```

El código JS que realiza la suma es este:

```js
function sumados() {
 var aa = document.getElementById('totEfectivo').value;
 var bb = document.getElementById('totaltdc').value;
 var rr = parseInt(aa) + parseInt(bb);
 document.getElementById('finturno').value = rr;
}
```

Sin embargo, cuando la función se dispara, sólo toma el valor del resultante input name="totEfectivo". Al ingresar datos en el otro bloque, para obtener el dato del input name="totaltdc" lo ignora por completo.

La función se dispara, pero no toma en cuenta el último valor de la suma, por ende el resultado de 'totEfectivo' lo coloca en el input destino name="diferencia"

Alguna ayuda?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola! Por lo que revisé parece bien el código. Tendría que verlo completo para detectar algún error. Puede que sea un tema de uso también, que te dé una sensación equivocada, prueba con **onkeyup** en lugar de **onchange**. El evento onchange se desencadena cuando se pierde el focus del input, mientras que el evento onkeyup se desencadena cuando sueltas la tecla. Quizás hay algún onchange que no se carga antes de realizar el cálculo. Sin mencionar que onkeyup se ve mucho más fluido.

Por otro lado, si tengo una sugerencia para que sea más ordenado y evitar errores: En lugar de poner funciones restar(), sumar(), multiplicar(), etc. Podrías poner atributos en el tag que tengan algún significado para una única función de procesamiento. Por ejemplo:

```
<script>
calcular(){
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for(input in inputs){
    if(input.hasAttribute('data-operation')){
      if(input.getAttribute('data-operation') == 'multiplicar'){
        //Lógica multiplicación.-
      }
      if(input.getAttribute('data-operation') == 'sumar'){
        //Lógica suma.-
      }
      //Usar data-operate-with en caso de que deba ser una operación con determinado parámetro.-
      //Usar otros atributos data-* para determinar por ejemplo en qué campo debe mostrarse el resultado.-
    }
  } 
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="a" data-operation="multiplicar" data-operate-with="B" onkeyup="calcular();"/>
```

También te recomendaría usar jquery: https://jquery.com/

Espero te sirva,
¡Saludos y éxito!

Comment: Hola Sebastián! Lo probaré así, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

buenas tardes, intenta con esto a ver si te resulta..

```js
function sumados() {
 var aa = document.getElementById('totEfectivo').value;
 var bb = document.getElementById('totaltdc').value;
 var rr = parseInt(aa.value) + parseInt(bb.value);
 document.getElementById('finturno').value = rr;
}
```